# Python short circuit with a lambda expression raises syntax error

Tags: python-3.x, lambda, short-circuiting

I wanted to return a lambda expression from a function if the argument to the function fulfills some criteria. I thought by writing something like the following this can be done:

```py
def f(x=None):
    return x or lambda:True    
f()
```

but the call raises a syntax error! Saving the lambda in a lexical variable does the work, but I am curious why is it not possible to write the expression above?

Comment: Interestingly, `return x or (lambda: True)` works fine, which indicates this is an issue with ambiguity with the `:` character, where python thinks you're trying to start a new block.

Comment: I thought the semicolon `:` is an integrated part of a python `lambda` expression!

Comment: I've looked through the cpython source code a bit, and haven't found enough to come up with a sufficiently conclusive/well-cited answer. However, I think that what's happening here is that the parser is confusing `lambda:True` for an annotated variable `lambda` of type `True`, and type annotations aren't legal within an expression. This probably has to do with parse order, and might be worth filing an official bug report for, since I can't find this behavior documented anywhere.